# NoSuchFieldError - IntelliJ 10

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I currently have two projects.  One being my main project which is TOMCAT/JSP and the second project being a jar library I'm working on.

The project I'm making a jar out of is fairly straight forward and after initally building/making and having it output a .jar file I went to the library section of the main project and pointed to it.  Everything worked as expected until I tried to add additional functionality to the jar.

In that second project I added a new field to an enumeration.  Now when trying to access it in the main project I'm getting the error in my TOMCAT log.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MY_NEW_FIELD
```

I've tried deleting the jar from the output, removing the link from the library and rebuilding.  Nothing seems to fix it.  Is there something similar to "clean" that I can use to resolve this, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: can you open the jar file, extract the class and run `javap` on it to see if the field is actually there? also, how do you package the war file you deploy?

Comment: Yea, I created a new project called SanityCheck.  And in it I go 
System.out.println(MyEnum_MY_NEW_Field.getDisplayValue());

And it shows in the output.

I deploy the package by going to project structure - artificats - jar.  Then I have the output layout be the name of the Jar and it nicludes the Project Library &  has a compile output.  That pushes the .jar to an out\artifcats folder

Comment: `File` | `Invalidate Caches` may help, note that IDEA or Tomcat can cache the jars. The proper way of setting this up is using a single project with 2 modules, instead of adding a jar to the dependencies, add a module to the dependency, this way IDEA should be able to handle the changes properly.